# Accessing XML properties that have colon in the name with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to get video info from a YouTube XML feed such as the title and thumbnail URL.

Let's take this feed as an example:
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/CevxZvSJLk8`

Here's the code I have now:

```
$videoURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/CevxZvSJLk8';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($videoURL);
print_r($sxml);
```

However, that doesn't seem to be including the media:group part of the xml sheet.

Essentially, I'm trying to get these two values:

```
entry -> media:group -> media:title
entry -> media:group -> media:thumbnail
```

EDIT: This is the solution I ended up going with from reading other similar questions.

```
$videoTitle = $sxml->children('media', true)->group->title;
$videoThumbnail = $sxml->children('media', true)->group->thumbnail->attributes()->url;
```

Comment: 1) Do not use `print_r()`, `var_dump()`, etc with SimpleXML; they will lie to you. 2) Search StackOverflow for "simplexml colon", "simplexml namespace", etc; this question has been asked about a million times already.

Comment: Ok that other answer helped me figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The colon in a tag name separates the namespace prefix from the local element or attribute name. The feed in the question has several namespaces.

- `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`
- `http://purl.org/atom/app#` with prefix `app`
- `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/` with prefix `media`
- `http://schemas.google.com/g/2005` with prefix `gd`
- `http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007` with prefix `yt`

The namespace prefix is an alias for the actual namespace, it is only valid for the document and can change for child nodes. The next feed could use the prefix `atom` for `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. So depending on the namespace prefix from the document is a bad idea.

If you use Xpath fo fetch the elements from a document, you can register your own prefixes for the used namespaces. The following example fetches the media rss title and the url of the large thumbnail directly as strings. If an element does not exists, it will return an empty string.

```
$videoURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/CevxZvSJLk8';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($videoURL);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('mrss', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//mrss:title)', NULL, FALSE),
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//mrss:thumbnail[@width="480"]/@url)', NULL, FALSE)
);
```

Output:

```
string(28) "Katy Perry - Roar (Official)"
string(40) "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/CevxZvSJLk8/0.jpg"
```

Comment: Nice introduction, but the proposed solution brings in two technologies the OP wasn't previously using (DOM and XPath) rather than just using the namespace functions of SimpleXML itself (`->children($ns)` and `->attributes($ns)`).

Comment: Yep @IMSoP is correct.  This is what I ended up doing: `$sxml->children('media', true)->group->title;` for title and `$sxml->children('media', true)->group->thumbnail->attributes()->url;` to get the url.

Comment: The SimpleXML variant is less stable, valid changes in the XML namespace prefix and missing elements (the external resource) can result in PHP errors.

Comment: @ThW Yes, the use of the `true` in `->children()` means relying on the prefix not changing; without that, it expects the full namespace URI, so is as safe as XPath. If I understand you right, missing elements (invalid input) will be issues with most ways of traversing XML. I would also note that SimpleXML also has an `->xpath()` method, which requires less boilerplate (no extra object) than the DOM version.

Comment: SimpleXMLs xpath() method can not return scalars, only node lists. The lists can be empty, so additional validation is required. Talking about boilerplate, try writing the second expression (first thumbnail with a specific width) using SimpleXml.

Comment: @ThW Sure, XPath is useful, but where in the question does it say the OP is trying to get "the first thumbnail with a specific width"? I could equally come up with scenarios which are really awkward with XPath, but easy with traversal of the kind SimpleXML makes easy. The same could be said for your clever trick of turning "no match" into an empty string: you might well *want* to detect that as a distinct case; if not `(string)$xpath_results[0]` would at worst issue a Notice while giving the same fallback. None of this has anything to do with the question, which was about namespace handling.