# Weird XML tags that cannot be read in php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an xml file in php, but I get empty object every time. Here is the xml content I get from the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<fe:ClubData xmlns:fe="http://fifa.com/exchange/fe" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
<fe:Club StadiumId="1883" PresidentName="Александар Панов">
    <fe:ClubPhotoLink mimeType="image/jpeg">\Club\121_1375270840626</fe:ClubPhotoLink>
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="121" Name="Фудбалски клуб МЕТАЛУРГ" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Металург">
        <fe:Address Town="Скопје" AddressLine1="16-та Македонска Бригада бр.18-Скопје-Гази Баба"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Металург"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб МЕТАЛУРГ"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
    <fe:TeamColour PrimaryShirtColour="fafafa" PrimaryShortColour="f5faf5" PrimarySockColour="f9fcf9" SecondaryShirtColour="000000"/>
    <fe:TeamColour PrimaryShirtColour="32af32" PrimaryShortColour="32b032" PrimarySockColour="ffffff" SecondaryShirtColour="000000"/>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1880" PresidentName="Драган Попоски">
    <fe:ClubPhotoLink mimeType="image/jpeg">/Club/FC_Rabotnicki.jpg</fe:ClubPhotoLink>
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="277" Name="Фудбалски клуб Работнички Скопје" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Работнички" ValidFrom="1937-07-14Z">
        <fe:Address Town="Скопје" AddressLine1="ул Македонија бр.10/1-1, 1000 Скопје"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Работнички"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Работнички Скопје"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1896" PresidentName="Весел Мемеди">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="209" Name="Фудбалски Клуб &quot;КФГ ГОСТИВАР&quot; Гостивар" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="КФГ Гостивар">
        <fe:Address Town="Гостивар" AddressLine1="Ул. Браќа Ѓиновски бб Гостивар"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="КФГ Гостивар"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски Клуб &quot;КФГ ГОСТИВАР&quot; Гостивар"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1926" PresidentName="Даскалов Горан">
    <fe:ClubPhotoLink mimeType="image/jpeg">/Club/images.jpg</fe:ClubPhotoLink>
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="100" Name="Здружение Фудбалски клуб БРЕГАЛНИЦА 2008 Штип" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Брегалница 2008">
        <fe:Address Town="Штип" AddressLine1="ул. ПАРТИЗАНСКА бр.ББ Штип"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Брегалница 2008"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Здружение Фудбалски клуб БРЕГАЛНИЦА 2008 Штип"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
    <fe:TeamColour PrimaryShirtColour="26358a" PrimaryShortColour="152b96" PrimarySockColour="2a3896" SecondaryShirtColour="000000"/>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1974" PresidentName="Нуриман Шаќири">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="124" Name="Фудбалски клуб Шкендија , Тетово" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Шкендија">
        <fe:Address Town="Тетово" AddressLine1="Ул. Благоја Тоска , Бр. бб&#xD;&#xA;1200 Тетово"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Шкендија"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Шкендија , Тетово"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="49583" PresidentName="Орце Тодоров">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="201" Name="фудбалски клуб ХОРИЗОНТ ТУРНОВО с.Турново Босилово" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Хоризонт Турново">
        <fe:Address Town="с.Турново" AddressLine1="с.Турново б.б"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Хоризонт Турново"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="фудбалски клуб ХОРИЗОНТ ТУРНОВО с.Турново Босилово"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1981" PresidentName="Божиноски Илија">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="163" Name="Младински Фудбалски Клуб Напредок Кичево" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Напредок">
        <fe:Address Town="Кичево" AddressLine1="Ул. Димитар Влахов бр.7 Кичево"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Напредок"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Младински Фудбалски Клуб Напредок Кичево"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1974" PresidentName="Јонуз Рустеми">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="123" Name="Трговско друштво за производство, трговија, угостителство и услуги Фудбалски клуб Ренова ДООЕЛ                     с. Џепчиште" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Ренова">
        <fe:Address Town="с. Џепчиште" AddressLine1="с. Џепчиште &#xD;&#xA;1200 Тетово"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Ренова"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Трговско друштво за производство, трговија, угостителство и услуги Фудбалски клуб Ренова ДООЕЛ                     с. Џепчиште"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="2035" PresidentName="Димче Шеровски">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="224" Name="Фудбалски клуб Пелистер" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Пелистер">
        <fe:Address Town="Битола" AddressLine1="ул. Томаки Димитровски 7-1"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Пелистер"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Пелистер"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="2044" PresidentName="Владо Крстевски">
    <fe:ClubPhotoLink mimeType="image/png">\Club\235_1367482030447</fe:ClubPhotoLink>
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="235" Name="Фудбалски клуб ЕУРОМИЛК Горно Лисиче" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Еуромилк Г.Л.">
        <fe:Address Town="Горно Лисиче - Скопје" AddressLine1="Ул.Горно Лисиче Бр.бб Скопје"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Еуромилк Г.Л."/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб ЕУРОМИЛК Горно Лисиче"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1880" PresidentName="Зоран Шишковски">
    <fe:ClubPhotoLink mimeType="image/jpeg">/Club/logo_malo.jpg</fe:ClubPhotoLink>
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="283" Name="Друштво за спортски дејности ФУДБАЛСКИ КЛУБ ВАРДАР АД Скопје" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Вардар">
        <fe:Address Town="Скопје" AddressLine1="бул. Илинден бб Скопје-Центар&#xD;&#xA;Поштенски фах 77"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Вардар"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Друштво за спортски дејности ФУДБАЛСКИ КЛУБ ВАРДАР АД Скопје"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1899" PresidentName="Копчаровски Љупчо">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="117" Name="Македонија Ѓорче Петров 1932 АД" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Македонија Ѓорче Петров 1932 АД">
        <fe:Address Town="Ѓорче Петров,Скопје" AddressLine1="ул.Мице Козар б.б. Ѓорче Петров , Скопје"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Македонија Ѓорче Петров 1932 АД"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Македонија Ѓорче Петров 1932 АД"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="2026" PresidentName="Рефик мустафи">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="238" Name="фудбалски клуб Врапчиште с.Врапчиште" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Врапчиште">
        <fe:Address Town="Врапчиште" AddressLine1="ул.Врапчиште бб Врапчиште &#xD;&#xA;Врапчиште"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Врапчиште"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="фудбалски клуб Врапчиште с.Врапчиште"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="2019" PresidentName="Самет Расими">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="196" Name="Фудбалски клуб Руфеја с. Милетино, Брвеница" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Руфеја">
        <fe:Address Town="с. Милетино, Брвеница" AddressLine1="Ул. 101, Бр. бб, Милетино&#xD;&#xA;Брвеница"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Руфеја"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Руфеја с. Милетино, Брвеница"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="2048">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="246" Name="Здружение фудбалски клуб Новаци 2005" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Новаци 2005">
        <fe:Address Town="Новаци" AddressLine1=""/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Новаци 2005"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Здружение фудбалски клуб Новаци 2005"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1885" PresidentName="Зоран Заев">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="319" Name="Фудбалски клуб Тиверија Струмица" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Тиверија Струмица">
        <fe:Address Town="Струмица" AddressLine1="Моша Пијаде бр.39"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Тиверија Струмица"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Тиверија Струмица"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1931" PresidentName="Доневски Ѓорѓи">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="156" Name="Фудбалски клуб „Маџари Солидарност92„-Скопје" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Маџари-Солидарност 92">
        <fe:Address Town="н.Маџари-ГазиБаба-Скопје" AddressLine1="бр.Општина/ГазиБаба Скопје-Гази Баба"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Маџари-Солидарност 92"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб „Маџари Солидарност92„-Скопје"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1887">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="306" Name="Фудлбаски Клуб 11 Октомври" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="11 Октомври">
        <fe:Address Town="Прилеп" AddressLine1="ул. Александар Македонски бб"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="11 Октомври"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудлбаски Клуб 11 Октомври"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1879" PresidentName="Власте Савевски">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="182" Name="Фудбалски клуб силекс кратово" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Силекс">
        <fe:Address Town="кратово" AddressLine1="Стадион на силекс бб"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Силекс"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб силекс кратово"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1921" PresidentName="Штерјов Васил">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="194" Name="Фудбалски клуб Миравци" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Миравци">
        <fe:Address Town="Миравци" AddressLine1="Ул. Миравци-бб Миравци&#xD;&#xA;Гевгелија"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Миравци"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Миравци"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
    <fe:TeamColour PrimaryShirtColour="ffffff" PrimaryShortColour="ffffff" PrimarySockColour="ffffff" SecondaryShirtColour="ffffff"/>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1974" PresidentName="Стеван Алампиоски">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="125" Name="Фудбалски клуб Тетекс Тетово" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Тетекс">
        <fe:Address Town="Тетово" AddressLine1="Ул. Браќа Миладинови , Бр. бб&#xD;&#xA;1200 Тетово"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Тетекс"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Тетекс Тетово"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1893" PresidentName="Матевски Владо">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="211" Name="Здружение на граЖани Фудбалски клуб Локомотива-Бентоекспорт Скопје" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Локомотива-Бентоекспорт">
        <fe:Address Town="Скопје" AddressLine1="ул„Булевар Илинден„ бр.ББ Скопје-н.Карпош"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Локомотива-Бентоекспорт"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Здружение на граЖани Фудбалски клуб Локомотива-Бентоекспорт Скопје"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1887">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="305" Name="Фудбалски Клуб ПОБЕДА ЈУНИОР" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Победа Јуниор">
        <fe:Address Town="Прилеп" AddressLine1="ул. Александар Македонски бб"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Победа Јуниор"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски Клуб ПОБЕДА ЈУНИОР"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1930" PresidentName="Треневски Томе">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="237" Name="Младинско Спортско друштво Скопје-Фудбалски клуб„СКОПЈЕ„" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="СКОПЈЕ">
        <fe:Address Town="Скопје" AddressLine1="ул„Јани Лукровски„ бр.6 Скопје-&#xD;&#xA;Гази Баба"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="СКОПЈЕ"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Младинско Спортско друштво Скопје-Фудбалски клуб„СКОПЈЕ„"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="2101">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="321" Name="Фудбалски клуб КОРЗО" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Корзо">
        <fe:Address Town="Прилеп" AddressLine1="Градски парк бб Прилеп"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Корзо"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб КОРЗО"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="2031" PresidentName="Абедин Алити">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="219" Name="Фудбалски клуб Дрита , с. Боговиње" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Дрита">
        <fe:Address Town="с. Боговиње" AddressLine1="с. Боговиње"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Дрита"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Дрита , с. Боговиње"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="1988" PresidentName="Киро Јачев">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="157" Name="Здружение на граѓани - Фудбалски клуб БОРЕЦ 2009 Велес" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Борец 2009">
        <fe:Address Town="Велес" AddressLine1="Ул. Алексо Демниевски - Бауман бр. ББ"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Борец 2009"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Здружение на граѓани - Фудбалски клуб БОРЕЦ 2009 Велес"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
<fe:Club StadiumId="2118" PresidentName="Ахмеди Фекри 0303964433022">
    <fe:OrganizationType OrganizationId="342" Name="Фудбалски клуб Зајази с.Зајас" OrganizationType="Club" ShortName="Зајази">
        <fe:Address Town="село Зајас" AddressLine1="село Зајас"/>
        <fe:Discipline>Football</fe:Discipline>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Зајази"/>
        <fe:NativeName Language="Фудбалски клуб Зајази с.Зајас"/>
    </fe:OrganizationType>
</fe:Club>
</fe:ClubData>
```

**EDIT**

Okay, things moved a little... when those `fe:` prefixes are removed I can read the contents... what do they mean and how can I avoid this conflict, as I am not generating the xml files? Should I read the file as string, do str_replace and then import it as xml file or is there a more elegant solution?

I edited the question and tags, as this is not a CakePHP problem, I tested in a script also.

Comment: The `fe` is a namespace prefix for the namespace `http://fifa.com/exchange/fe`. You need to register the namespace to fetch data. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21350445/2265374

Comment: Yep, this solved it. If you want you can post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if your XML is valid using Firefox browser. Simply open your file in browser. XML files cannot be partially valid, they can by valid or !valid.

Comment: It displays fine in Firefox, seems valid. I found the root of the problem, the question is edited now. Any solution to that would be appreciated.